# Uniform bound for a family of linear operators on $L^2$

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces, harmonic-analysis, estimation

> Let $\phi,\psi$ be functions on $\mathbb{R}^d$ with
>   $\int\phi=\int\psi=0$ and
>   $$|\phi(x)|,|\psi(x)|\lesssim(1+|x|)^{-(d+1)}
>   \quad\text{and}\quad
>   |\nabla\phi(x)|,|\nabla\psi(x)|\lesssim(1+|x|)^{-(d+2)}.
> $$
>   Let $\phi_t(x)=t^{-d}\phi(x/t)$ and similarly for $\psi$.
>   For $R>1$ define the operator
>   $$T_R f:=\int_{1/R}^R\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}(f*\psi_t)(y)
>   \phi_t(\cdot-y)\mathrm{d}y\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{t}.
> $$

I have to show that $T_R$ is uniformly bounded in $L^2(\mathbb R^d)$ for $R>1$.
There is a hint which suggests to use the duality of $L^2$ and the almost orthogonality lemma which says the following:

> Let $\varphi:\mathbb R^d\rightarrow\mathbb R$ be a function such that for all $z,z'\in\mathbb R^d$ we have:
>   1. $\int_{\mathbb R^d}\varphi=0$
>   2. $|\varphi(z)|\leq(1+|z|)^{-(d+1)}$
>   3. $|\varphi(z)-\varphi'(z)|\leq|z-z'|((1+|z|)^{-(d+1)}+(1+|z'|)^{-(d+1)})$.
>   Let $\varphi_{y,t}(z)=t^{-d}\varphi(t^{-1}(y-z))$. 
>   Then $$|\langle\varphi_{y,t},\varphi_{y',t'}\rangle|\leq\frac{tt'}{\max(t,t')+|y-y'|^{d+1}}.$$

So I've gotten to this estimate
$$T_R f(x)\lesssim
      \int_{1/R}^R |\langle f*\varphi_t,\varphi_{x,t}
      \rangle|\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{t}
      \lesssim\int_{1/R}^R\frac{t}{t+|x|^{d+1}}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{t}
      \leq\int_{1/R}^R\frac{1}{t}\mathrm{d}t
      =2\ln(R),$$
but I feel like it is not good enough, since it does not give the independence on $R>1$.

In part two it asks to show that $\lim_{R,R'\rightarrow\infty}\|T_R f-T_{R'}f\|_{L^2}=0$.
I imagine it follows from the uniform bound, but I suspect I have to do the estimate of the above first so that i can estimate the limit and then pass to the second limit.

**EDIT**:
I think I got a decent attempt.
Let $\mathcal F:g\mapsto\widehat{g}$ denote the Fourier transform operator
and let $\phi_{y,t}:=\phi_t(y-x)$. 
Then
$$|\langle T_R f,g \rangle|
      \leq\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}g(x)\int_{1/R}^R\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}
        (f*\psi_t)(y)\phi_t(x-y)
        \mathrm{d}y\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{t}\mathrm{d}x
$$
$$\overset{\text{Fubini}}=\int_{1/R}^R
        \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}(f*\psi_t)(y)
        \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}g(x)\phi_t(x-y)
        \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{t}
$$
$$=\int_{1/R}^R
        \langle f*\psi_t,g*\phi_{0,t} \rangle
        \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{t}   
      \overset{\text{Plancherel}}=\int_{1/R}^R
        \langle \mathcal{F}(f*\psi_t),\mathcal{F}(g*\phi_{0,t})\rangle
        \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{t}
$$
$$=\int_{1/R}^R
        \langle\widehat f\cdot\widehat\psi_t,
        \widehat g\cdot\widehat\phi_{0,t}) \rangle
        \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{t}
$$
$$\leq C|\langle f,g \rangle|
        \int_{1/R}^R\langle\psi_t,\phi_{0,t}\rangle\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{t}
$$
$$\overset{\text{lemma from above??}}\leq
        C'|\langle f,g \rangle|
$$
I feel like this last step does not work.
However, if it does work, then choosing $g=T_R f$ gives
$$\|T_R f\|_{L^2}
      \leq\frac{C'}{\|T_R f\|_{L^2}}|\left\langle f,T_R f \right\rangle|
      \overset{\text{Cauchy-Schwarz}}\leq
      C'\frac{\|T_R f\|_{L^2}}{\|T_R f\|_{L^2}}\|f\|_{L^2}
      =C'\|f\|_{L^2}$$
for all $R>1$.

For part 2 I had the following idea:
Let $1<R'<R$. Then
    \begin{align*}
  |\langle T_R f-T_{R'} f,g \rangle|
  &\overset{\text{part (a)}}\leq
    C|\langle f,g\rangle|
    \underbrace{\left( \int_{1/R}^{1/R'}
    |\langle \psi_t,\phi_{0,t} \rangle|
    \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{t}
  +\int_{R'}^R
    |\langle \psi_t,\phi_{0,t} \rangle|
    \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{t}
     \right)}_{\text{bounded independently of }R>R'}
\end{align*}
    Therefore
$$\lim_{R'\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}|\langle T_R f-T_{R'} f,g \rangle|
\leq\lim_{R'\rightarrow\infty}
C|\langle f,g\rangle|
\left( \int_0^{1/R'}
|\langle \psi_t,\phi_{0,t} \rangle|
\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{t}
+\int_{R'}^\infty
|\langle \psi_t,\phi_{0,t} \rangle|
\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{t}
\right)
=0$$
Hence $\lim_{R,R'\rightarrow\infty}\|T_R f-T_{R'}f\|_{L^2}=0$.